# Finding a curve from its evolute

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, frenet-frame

Consider the evolute given by
$$ \gamma: I \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{E}^2: t \mapsto (\cos(t),\sin(t))$$
Now, how do I find all the curves $\alpha$ that have $\gamma$ as their involute?
I tried using the fact that an involute is given by
$$\gamma(t) = \alpha(t) + \frac{1}{\kappa(t)}N(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t)) $$
so that also 
$$\gamma'(t) = \left(\frac{1}{\kappa(t)}\right)'N(t)= (-\sin(t),\cos(t))$$
and then using the Frenet-Serret formula's, but I haven't gotten very far...

Answer (score -1):

Hint: [The involute of an evolute is the original curve.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolute) and [the evolute of an involute is the original curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involute).

Comment: This is not the problem I am stating. I am giving the involute $\gamma$ of a curve, and I need to find the curve(s) $\alpha$ of which $\gamma$ is the involute.

Comment: My apologies - I quoted it the wrong way around. In any case, taking the involute and evolute are inverse to one another.

Comment: If $inv(\alpha)=\gamma$, then $ev(\gamma)=\alpha$

Comment: So you say that the involute of the involute of any curve is the curve itself? How do you prove this?

Comment: In fact, I think this is plain wrong. The involute of a circle is a point. The involute of a point is not even defined.

Comment: You make a good point, though I think the problem arises in finding the evolute of a point instead. There's also a slight distinguishing point I missed in that the involute seems to have a degree of freedom, so having an inverse may not quite work. In any case, I can recommend having a look at [this](https://www.ndsu.edu/pubweb/~cope/TEACHING/Math_460_660/2D_30_Evolutes_Involutes_121014.pdf), which gives a proof of "the evolute of the involute is the original curve" which, after setting up the notation, works quite nicely.

Comment: Also, I'm not saying "involute of the involute of any curve is the curve itself", I'm saying "evolute of the involute of any curve is the curve itself".

Comment: So in fact, what you are saying is that $\alpha(t) = \gamma(t) - sT(t)$?